# Posting an open access IEEE paper to Researchgate

Tags: publications, journals, copyright

I am wondering if I can upload my accepted early access IEEE paper to Researchgate for public viewing?

The paper has the following "This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 License. For more information, see [https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/"](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/%22)

On the website above, it says "You are free to: Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format"

So it seems that the answer is yes but I just to make sure since I am not that experienced with this.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.ieee.org/publications/rights/author-posting-policy.html

Comment: Thanks. From this, it states that "posting of the final PDF, as published by IEEE Xplore®, continues to be prohibited, except for open-access journal articles supported by payment of an article processing charge (APC), whose authors may freely post the final version." So I assume that the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, but you can post the one you submitted for review.   My interpretation is that it is OK as long you don't post the final version that is posted on IEEE Explorer.

Comment: Even for open access?

Comment: from the URL provided above: "except for open-access journal articles supported by payment of an article processing charge (APC), whose authors may freely post the final version."